# Set part of string as percentage

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

Been trying to get a msgbox to show a range of cells that user can see and use. This needs to be a list from two columns in another sheet in my Workbook. Got the most of the code done, but I'm getting an output that I can't get my head around.

in the code I want the `NCol` to be shown as percentage when msgbox prompts.

First idea was to set each cell in that that variable to `Format(NCol,"0.00%")` after the `For NCol = ...`.

Second idea was inside the `Str & Rng.Cells...Format(Ncol..` which obviously didn't go as wanted.

Any pointers in the right direction is much appreciated. picture below shows outcome in msgbox.
Input

[image: Input and wanted output look]

outcome

[image: Outcome to msgbox]

```
Sub ShowTopCat()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ACell As Range
    Dim Str As String
    Dim ARow As Long
    Dim NCol As Long
    Dim art As Worksheet
    Set art = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng = art.Range("x2:y101")
    If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    For ARow = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
        For NCol = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count
                Str = Str & Rng.Cells(ARow, NCol).Value & vbTab
        Next
        Str = Str & vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox Str, vbInformation, "You top cats"
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use `Right()` or `Split()` to get the number part of the string and store it in a `Double`. You can then manipulate that?

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: @Tom Edited the question with picture if the range the msgbox gets values from

Comment: Sorry, but for me it's totally unclear what are you trying to get

Comment: Was just going to say, `Format(NCol, "0.00%")` would work with me (if `Ncol` is a reference to a number) to get it in a `MsgBox`. Otherwise, maybe your looking for `NumberFormat` to format your actual cells?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns in the code I want the `NCol` to be shown as percentage when msgbox prompts. Atm im stuck in how to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use two loops when your range is fixed?

```
Sub ShowTopCat()
    Dim art As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Str As String
    Dim ARow As Long

    Set art = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng = art.Range("x2:y101")
    If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next

    For ARow = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
        With Rng.Cells(ARow, 1)
            If .Value2 <> vbNullString Then
                Str = Str & .Value2 & vbTab & Format(.Offset(0, 1).Value2, "0" & Application.DecimalSeparator & "00%")
                Str = Str & vbCrLf
            End If
        End With
    Next ARow
    MsgBox Str, vbInformation, "You top cats"
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks tom. It looks correct but it gives me the last in range for some reason.

Comment: @krib What do you mean by 'last in range'?

Comment: the `Range("X2:Y101")` is filled with categories in `X` and values as percentage in `Y`. This code only gives the last row of value. Ive used all range. I've modified it to `Y12`cause I know the range is to much for a msgbox, butil still gives me whats in `X12:Y12`.

Comment: it's so close, but its still not storing all values to the string. I cant see whats up myself. But the values are correct, so thats giving me some ideas

Comment: @krib - It works fine in my tests however, the code skips over any rows where column `X` is blank? Is this what you mean?

Comment: your last edit gives me the entire list as wantet, now its just a formating thing; the values in `Y` is shown `004%` rather then `4,0%`. i just removed your ` & Application...` and used your old format setup

Comment: @krib - It is due to we're using different decimal separators. Have updated so it should use your locale now instead of mine